# What is the difference between the Grothendieck and the Čech cohomology?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology, coherent-sheaves

Grothendieck has proven that whenever $X\longrightarrow\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ is a proper morphism of Noetherian schemes, $F$ is coherent over $X$ and flat over $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$, then there exists a finite complex of finitely generated projective modules over $A$
\begin{equation*}
    0\longrightarrow K^{0}\longrightarrow...\longrightarrow K^{n}\longrightarrow 0
\end{equation*}
such that for any $A$-module $M$ there exists an isomorphism of $A$-modules
\begin{equation*}
    H^{p}(X,F\otimes_{A}M)\cong H^{p}(K\otimes_{A}M)\text{.}
\end{equation*}
So far, so good. Is not the Čech complex precisely one example of such a Grothendieck complex? By construction, the Čech complex consists of projective modules, and it satisfies the isomorphism condition.

Comment: The modules in the Cech complex aren’t finitely generated over $A$!

Comment: @Mindlack that looks like an answer to me - would you care to record it below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that the groups of the Cech complex aren’t finitely generated except when $X$ is finite over $A$. I’m studying the cohomology of $\mathcal{O}_X$.

Indeed, let $X=\cup_i{U_i}$ be a finite affine cover. Thus every finite intersection of the $U_i$ is affine and the Cech complex computes the sheaf cohomology.

$\bigoplus_i{\mathcal{O}_X(U_i)}$ is the first nonzero group in the Cech complex, so if it is finitely generated, then all the $\mathcal{O}_X(U_i)$ are finitely generated $A$-modules, thus they are finite (hence proper) over $A$, and thus are closed in $X$, so that $X$ is the disjoint reunion of the $U_i$ which are finite.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can anyone give me a good reference on the topic? In particular, I need to understand why the $K^{i}$ making up the Grothendieck complex are projective. The only good source I found is https://amathew.wordpress.com/2011/01/09/the-grothendieck-complex/, but they only prove flatness of the $K^{i}$ there. Any idea? Google is notoriously bad at delivering useful results related to theoretical mathematics.

Comment: They also prove the finiteness of the complex (finitely many finitely generated modules). The notes seem to have a tex version here: http://math.uchicago.edu/~amathew/semicontinuity.pdf . The author also proves a few consequences that are interesting in their own right. For projectivity, I found the statement here: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07VJ . So all you have to do is follow the dependencies up (and you might manage to simplify the proof somewhat).

Comment: Although in the tex notes, the construction is made so that the modules are free everywhere except in degree $0$, and it may be enough to show projectivity.

Comment: I am really having trouble showing the projectivity of $K^{0}$ as constructed in [math.uchicago.edu/~amathew/semicontinuity.pdf]. Anyone has an idea? Where is Grothendieck's work on this to be found?

Comment: In fact, the answer based on the “amathew” construction seems rather easy. It looks like a very general argument but I don’t know the details well (I hope I’m not wrong): you can find a resolution $K_r \rightarrow K_{r-1} \rightarrow \ldots \rightarrow K_1 \rightarrow K$ where each $K_i$ has finitely generated free $A$-modules (because $A$ Noetherian) in degree $0 \leq j \leq n$ (bounds on $K$). Then you can construct another complex $K’$ made with a sort of “diagonal sum” of the $K_i$ (so with free finitely generated $A$-modules) whose image to $K$ is a quasi-isomorphism, so a universal one.

Comment: If one assumes $A$ to be hereditary, the argument actually becomes quite easy. There has to be a better source than stacks project, though Stacks project proofs are, as a general rule, a crime against humanity for their lack of readability.

Answer (score 0):

The argument becomes easy if $A$ is assumed hereditary. In the construction given in [https://amathew.wordpress.com/2011/01/09/the-grothendieck-complex], all $K^{i}$ are free for $i\geq 1$ and therefore projective. The module $K^{0}$ is a quotient of a free module $K'^{0}=F'\oplus F$, and we have maps $\alpha:F'\longrightarrow K^{1}$ and $\beta:F\longrightarrow K^{1}$. Since $C^{0}$ and $K^{1}$ are projective, so are the images $\operatorname{im}(\alpha)$ and $\operatorname{im}(\beta)$ (by hereditarity). Therefore, there exist splitting maps $\operatorname{im}(\alpha)\longrightarrow F$ and $\operatorname{im}(\beta)\longrightarrow F'$. The maps $K^{0}\longrightarrow C^{0}$ and $K^{0}\longrightarrow K^{1}$ factor as $K^{0}\longrightarrow\operatorname{im}(\alpha)\longrightarrow C^{0}$ and $K^{0}\longrightarrow\operatorname{im}(\beta)\longrightarrow K^{1}$. Let $\gamma$ denote the composite map $K^{0}\longrightarrow\operatorname{im}(\beta)\longrightarrow F\longrightarrow K'^{0}$ and $\delta$ the composite map $K^{0}\longrightarrow\operatorname{im}(\beta)\longrightarrow F'\longrightarrow K'^{0}$, and let $\zeta:K'^{0}\longrightarrow K^{0}$ be the quotient map. Then $\zeta\circ(\gamma\oplus\delta)=\operatorname{id}_{K^{0}}$, hence $K^{0}$ is a direct summand of $K'^{0}$ and therefore projective.

All in all, only the projectivity of $C^{0}$ was needed in the entire proof, hence the statement remains true if one demands projectivity only for $C^{0}$. Very intriguing and enlightening indeed!

This does however not prove the general (non-hereditary) case...

Comment: Why does the Cech complex consist of projective modules again? If $X$ is the closure in $\mathbb{P}^1$ of $V(Xf-1)\subset \mathbb{A}^1$, then one of the $U_i$ can be taken to be the spectrum of $A_f$ and $A_f$ is not projective as a $A$-module.

Comment: @Aphelli If we are working with $\mathbb{P}^1_R$ over a base ring $R$, then $A_f$ is not a projective over the $R$-algebra $A$, but it is projective over $R$, no?

Comment: @PrimeRibeyeDeal: I don’t understand what you’re asking. In my case $A$ is the base ring.

Comment: @Aphelli my apologies. The way I understood your example, if $A$ were the base ring, then the coordinate rings of $X$ appearing in the Cech complex would not be $A_f$, but things like $A[x]_f$ and $A[x^{\pm 1}]_f$. But perhaps I was mistaken.

Comment: @PrimeRibeyeDeal: no, you’rr correct. But I’m not sure these modules are projective over $A$ – and in any case they’re not finitely generated.